# Allow variable amount of comments before pagination

Tags: posts, comments, pagination

There is an option in the admin settings allowing you to define how many comments should be listed before creating a new page for the next ones. I would like to have the same number of comments for all my posts unless it belongs to one specific category (where I would like to set a different number of comments before pagination).

How can I do that?

Comment: I asked this question many times and never got an answer. Is it impossible to achieve or am I not clear about the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This have several components to it - what option itself holds and how value from it is stashed away and reused by various pieces of core code.

I am not sure this is perfect, but my quick take would be:

```
new Adjust_Comments_Per_Page( 10, 'years', 'category' );

class Adjust_Comments_Per_Page {

    private $amount;
    private $term;
    private $taxonomy;

    /**
     * @param int    $amount
     * @param string $term
     * @param string $taxonomy
     */
    function __construct( $amount, $term, $taxonomy ) {

        $this->amount   = $amount;
        $this->term     = $term;
        $this->taxonomy = $taxonomy;

        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'template_redirect' ) );
    }

    function template_redirect() {

        global $wp_query;

        if ( is_single() && has_term( $this->term, $this->taxonomy ) ) {

            $wp_query->set( 'comments_per_page', $this->amount );
            add_filter( 'pre_option_comments_per_page', array( $this, 'pre_option_comments_per_page' ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    function pre_option_comments_per_page() {

        return $this->amount;
    }
}
```